# Enabling GPU Frame Capture

Tags: xcode, macos, gpu, metal

I am trying to build a Metal compute application. I wrote my first kernel, and now I want to see it's output from the compute shader. But, the "GPU Frame Capture" options are disabled in XCode.
I'm using XCode 9.2. I have already enabled GPU Frame Capture in the schemes, that I'm running.
Any hint about, why this might be happening?

Comment: Since you're not actually presenting frames, Xcode doesn't know what constitutes a "frame". You will have to add programmatic begin- and end-scope markers. You can use `MTLCaptureManager` and `MTLCaptureScope` for that.

Comment: FWIW: I've never really had much success with this. The only way I could ever get GPU Frame Capture to work for compute kernels is to also do some graphics work with Metal at the same time (such as displaying AVCapture's preview layer).

Comment: @KenThomases I tired doing that. Didn't work. Somehow the `isCapturing` was false everytime. I was using `startCaptureWithDevice` and `stopCapture`. I wasn't making a `MTLCaptureScope` though. I just got a `sharedCaptureManager` and called startCapture.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans Apparently I am also writing the code in a application that does some rendering using Metal Apis. But the output of compute is not used there, probably, that is why I'm not able to capture frames.

Comment: You can try setting a breakpoint right before you create the `MTLCommandBuffer`, then edit the breakpoint and choose Add action -> capture GPU frame. 
Do note it tends to only work after the second compute dispatch though...

Comment: @Itai Tried doing that too. But of no use. Migrated to XCode 10.2. I can use GPU Frame capture with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you cannot debug compute shaders on XCode 9.2. I moved to Xcode 10.2, and I was able to use GPU Frame Capture to debug my Compute Kernels.

*P.S I'm not sure if this is a documented limitation, but this is what I experienced.*